reCAPTCHA v3 Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js
I'm trying to get reCaptcha V3 working on my Vue app and I'm seeing the error above when I try to submit the captcha.
I came across this GitHub discussion, but it didn't seem to resolve the issue: https://gist.github.com/shellj/afb66de1c6316d2316b4b14c979d271c

if you're going to downvote this, it would be helpful to explain why. I realize this was a stupid mistake but I think it could be helpful to people who Google this error message in the future.

I figured it out, it was happening because I had put my secret key in my frontend's environment file instead of the public "site key". The secret key goes in the backend environment file and the site key goes in the frontend environment file.
